# ASPX cache for local page objects?

Tags: asp.net, caching

Given the following test code, it seems an ASPX application puts locally generated objects in some kind of cache. Can this behavior be controlled in any way?

```
<%
    Response.Write(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()+"<br>");
    var ticks = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    var us = new UserSession("someguid"); // some custom object
    var elapsedTicks = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks-ticks;
    Response.Write(elapsedTicks.ToString()+"<br>");
%>
```

outputs:

```
636724515667290422
156249

636724516024946218
0

636724516212444985
0
```

(...)

```
636724516744942243
156251
```

Comment: It looks like the JIT removes the unused object. When I output an attribute of the object, I get ticks for every call. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it’s not any kind of cache, it’s the `DateTime` call it’s not so precise as you may believe. The reason is the speed... if you need more precision to measure the time you need to use the `stopwatch` class

Find some examples on this pages:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://www.dotnetperls.com/stopwatch

Comment: Ran over the Stopwatch class a little later after the post. Using this I always get a ticks value, even when the class variable is unused. Never thought that DateTime accuracy would be the problem, but it seems so.

Comment: @needfulthing Yes - think that its need to have some optimize because the call is actually done using an interrupt to the processor and asking the time - its a lot of costly...